# Recuperar el id de un proceso y su nombre de la pestaña del buscador

Tags: c#

Necesito recuperar el Id de proceso y el texto "WhatsApp - Google Chrome" en la pestaña del buscador, el lenguaje que uso es C#.

Para recuperar el Id del proceso, puedo utilizar

```
Process.GetProcesses();
```

y obtengo Process[] con todos los procesos pero necesito identificar este proceso y matarlo, únicamente ese proceso.

Gracias.

[image: I need recover the process Id and the text "WhatsApp - Google Chrome" in browser tab (is an example)]

Comment: Buenas Perci. Añade también el código que intentaste para identificar el proceso en concreto que quieres matar y explica por qué no te funcionó. Mira [ask] para más información. Un saludo

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que no son procesos diferentes. El proceso es único: el del navegador Chrome, no hay un proceso diferente por pestaña.

Puedes listar las ventanas abiertas por el navegador haciendo una búsqueda de procesos con el nombre 'chrome' y que tengan una ventana asociada:

```
var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
foreach (var process in processes.Where(p=> p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Process: {process.Id}\t{process.ProcessName}");
}
```

Para listar las pestañas puedes utilizar las clases del espacio de nombres `System.Windows.Automation`. Puedes añadir las referencias a estas librerías a tu proyecto incluyendo el paquete Nuget UIAComWrapper:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así podrías listar las pestañas abiertas en navegadores Chrome:

```
var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
foreach (var process in processes.Where(p=> p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Process: {process.Id}\t{process.ProcessName}");

    // Seleccionamos todos los elementos de tipo TabItem
    var root = AutomationElement.FromHandle(process.MainWindowHandle);
    var condIsTab = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.TabItem);
    var tabs = root.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, condIsTab);
    foreach (AutomationElement tabitem in tabs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\tTab: {tabitem.Current.Name}");
    }
}
```

Podrías matar el proceso de Chrome, pero eso cerraría la ventana completa del navegador. Si lo que quieres es quitar una única pestaña lo que puedes hacer es simular un click en el botón cerrar de la pestaña. Para ello el código debería seleccionar la pestaña (entiendo que por el nombre), localizar el botón cerrar y generar un click en la posición del botón. Si añades al proyecto el paquete Nuget Microsoft.TestApi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

podrías hacer algo así:

```
var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
foreach (var process in processes.Where(p=> p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Process: {process.Id}\t{process.ProcessName}");

    // Seleccionamos todos los elementos de tipo TabItem
    var root = AutomationElement.FromHandle(process.MainWindowHandle);
    var condIsTab = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.TabItem);
    var tabs = root.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, condIsTab);
    foreach (AutomationElement tabitem in tabs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\tTab: {tabitem.Current.Name}");
        if (tabitem.Current.Name.Contains("WhatsApp"))
        {
            var cerrar = tabitem.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children,
                new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Button));

            var clickPoint = cerrar.GetClickablePoint();
            Mouse.MoveTo(new System.Drawing.Point((int)clickPoint.X, (int)clickPoint.Y));
            Mouse.Click(MouseButton.Left);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Si no me equivoco, lo que dices (en la última parte) es emular un click sobre el botón de cerrar de una pestaña en chrome. Otra manera es, si estamos en la pestaña que deseamos cerrar, emular el pulsado de ctrl+f4 que cierra la pestaña, así te evitarías tener que buscar las coordenadas.

Comment: Habría que probarlo pero entiendo que primero habría que establecer la pestaña como activa ¿no?

Comment: Si, es lo que pretendía decir cuando he puesto: "si estamos en la pestaña que debemos cerrar", sorry por no expresarme bien.

Comment: Me gustaría puntualizar que en realidad tanto en chrome como en los navegadores modernos si que existe un proceso diferente por pestaña. Esto es asi para que en caso de que una pestaña se bloquee o tenga algun problema no afecte a las demás. De hecho hay una opción en chrome para ver los procesos,ahora no tengo un equipo delante pero existe. Buena opción la que propones de todas maneras,enhorabuena.

Comment: Gracias Asier, por esta solución. Pero me interesa más lo que puso Pikoh. Si fuese posible conseguir el ID del proceso que cierra la la pestaña si se hace un taskKill, y sirva para cualquier navegador sería mucho mejor.